# BigQuery-SQL - joining 2 table for revenue calculation

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I've the following 2 tables:

Table1 - raw data without revenue data:

```
datehour | geo | platform | dimension_4 | dimension_5
metric_1 | metric_2 | billable_actions (int)
```

Table2 - the revenue data, which is originated from another source
but eventually inserted into a table with the following schema
(please note that it has 2 missing dimensions):

```
datehour | geo | platform | revenue (float)
```

I need to merge Table2 into Table1 , 
so I can calculate the revenue only from table1.

**THE QUERY**

```
SELECT
 datehour,
 cc,
 platform,
 dimension_1,
 dimension_2,
 billable_actions,
 CASE
   WHEN revenue > 0 AND billable_actions > 0 THEN (revenue/total_billable_actions)*billable_actions
   WHEN metric_1 IS NULL AND metric_2 IS NULL THEN revenue
   ELSE 0
 END calc_revenue
FROM (
 SELECT
   IFNULL(e.datehour,d.from_ts) datehour,
   IFNULL(e.cc, d.cc) cc,
   IFNULL(e.platform, d.platform) platform,
   e.dimension1,
   e.dimension2,
   e.billable_actions,
   SUM(e.billable_actions) OVER (PARTITION BY e.datehour, e.platform, e.geo) total_billable_actions,
   d.revenue
 FROM Table1 e
 FULL JOIN Table2 d
 ON
  e.datehour = d.from_ts AND
  e.appkey = d.appkey AND
  e.cc = d.cc AND
  e.platform = d.platform
)
```

**EXPECTED RESULT & THE PROBLEM**

Both tables revenues should be equal after the join.
I'm testing:

```
select sum(revenue) from Table2 ==
select sum(row_revenue) from JoinedTable
```

but row_revenue is always lower:
Table2 sum = 0.44449199771042913
Joined table sum = 0.4421989977126941

Can some one please point me for the reason why they are not equal?
I've a working example at the end of the question .

**NOTES**

**note 1** - the revenue is calculated the following way:

1) Table1 FULL JOIN Table2 ON:

```
T1.datehour = T2.datehour AND
T1.geo = T2.geo AND
T1.platform = T2.platform
```

*please read note 2,3 regard why I use full join.

2) on Table1 , sum the billable actions, partition by datehour, geo and platform.

```
SUM(billable_actions) OVER (PARTITION BY datehour, geo, platform)  
AS total_billable_actions
```

3) Now , we have a table , where each row contains the total_billable_actions per the group , the total revenue and the total actions for the row. wrapping it with another select and calculating the row revenue:

```
row_revenue = (revenue / total_billable_actions) * billable_actions
```

**note 2**
we may have rows from Table1 which do not match any row from table2,
but we still need the data found in those rows . those rows will not affect the revenue calculations.

**note 3**
we may have rows from Table2 which also do not fit the join.
we need those rows , stay untouched , with the same revenue.

**note 4** regard floating point issues:
BigQuery uses 8byte double precision for float,
and I've multiplied all results with great numbers (1000, 1000000) to find out if the issue is decimal point precision.
It seems that multiplying the result gives the same exact result.

**working example**

for simplicity I've taken out one dimension and the other metrics.

Left table:

```
datehour   geo   platform   dimension_1   billable_actions
15:00      US    Android    shmoo         10
15:00      US    Android    foo           5
15:00      US    IOS        shmoo         8
15:00      US    IOS        foo           4
15:00      US    UNKNOWN    shmoo         4
```

Right table:

```
datehour  geo      platform   revenue
15:00     US       Android    5$
15:00     US       IOS        10$
15:00     UNKNOWN  IOS        2$
```

Joined table:

```
15:00   US      Android    shmoo         10  15  (5$/15)*10 = 3.333..3
15:00   US      Android    foo           5   15  (5$/15)*5 = 1.6666..7
15:00   US      IOS        shmoo         8   12  (10$/12)*8 = 6.6666..7
15:00   US      IOS        foo           4   12  (10$/12)*4 = 3.3333..3
15:00   US      UNKNOWN    shmoo         4   4   0$
15:00   UNKNOWN IOS        null          0   0   2$
```

sum(row_revenue) = 17$

Thanks all !

Comment: You should use NUMERIC instead of FLOAT64 to rule out precision loss

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard . I can't believe I missed it . Thx.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard , Hi !
Unfortunately it did not help , I'm getting a very very close result ,
i've also changed the full join into inner join for a sprcific period I know I don't have any leftovers (both left and right) but the revenue is still very close but not the same .
1) SOURCE  0.20103616

2) QUERY  0.200784255